# How do I export firebase admin in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to export firebase admin so that my modules can have access to it. Since I'm working with Typescript, it doesn't recognize admin's properties when i import it in my modules.

`admin.ts`

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

module.exports = admin;
```

import in `fbAuth.ts`

```
import * as admin from "./admin";
```

problematic line in `fbAuth.ts`

```
const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
```

error in `fbAuth.ts`

```
Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/borysserbyn/Documents/NTC/cloud-functions/functions/src/admin")'.ts(2339)
```

The reason im doing it this way is because I saw it in a tutorial. Would it be acceptable just to initializeApp() in every module or would that be bad?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so someone helped me find the answer. The problem is that module.export doesn't work with Typescript. Heres some documentation on exporting modules in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export.

export in `admin.ts`

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export {admin};
```